# Draw Curved Line between Two Points in Google Geo Chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

My intention is to have a map that contains multiple markers on different countries. The markers are connected each others. The countries/regions will have different colors based the numbers data related to each of those. 
Then, i have done with a simple map using Gmaps and managed to plot the markers and then connected each marker to others with customized curved line. I was using [this library](http://curved_lines.overfx.net/).

Yet now i'm facing one more trouble: how to deal with different colors for each country based on the numbers data related to each of those? Here i have an array containing the countries and numbers related t each of those and i want to differentiate the colors between those countries with smaller number results lighter color and bigger number results darker.

I have found [Google Geo Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) that makes it easy to implement and looks very beautiful. But how can i combine this advantage with the map i have made using Gmaps and the lines inside? I need a solution

Comment: i am facing similar problem and looking for the answer too..

Comment: Google's Visualization API GeoCharts are not compatible with Google Maps, nor can you draw lines on them like your Maps plugin allows.  You should look for a choropleth map (also called an intensity map or heat map) plugin for Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/)** is a good solution for you. It already supports heat maps on countries and markers. It can also be extend to support drawing lines between markers. Check with them for more info.

Here is the features of [VectorWorkz GeoCharts](http://vectorworkz.com/products/geochart/features).

The online demo of the [VectorWorkz GeoCharts](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/).